# Print Option stopped working in Adobe Acrobat Reader DC after upgrading to Windows 10 version 1809

Tags: windows-10, pdf, printing, adobe-reader, windows-10-v1809

Few days back, I upgraded my desktop (Windows 10 version 1803) to Windows 10 version 1809 using the update released through WSUS.

After the upgrade, I'm unable to print any PDF document in Abobe Acrobat Reader DC (version 2019.010.20064). What I mean is the document loads successfully and everything else is in place (within the options I use), except print. Whenever I click on Print, nothing happens. Also checked using Ctrl + P, but no difference.

Things I've tried (with no luck):

1. Installed latest updates for Windows 10 version 1809 (December, 2018)
2. Installed latest updates available for Abobe Acrobat Reader DC; no new updates available.
3. Uninstalled Abobe Acrobat Reader DC and then reinstalled the latest version from Adobe's website.

Alternate (working) ways to print PDF document:

1. Using Microsoft Edge browser to open and print PDF documents.

---

Could anyone please suggest/guide how to resolve this problem? I've searched everywhere across Internet, but couldn't find anything which would solve this case!

Comment: What happens if you use *File > Print*, click *Advanced*, then select *Print as Image*? Also try to disable [Protected mode](https://helpx.adobe.com/reader/using/protected-mode-windows.html#id_94783).

Comment: @harrymc - As I've already stated in the question, the dialog box for Print itself is not opening! So, neither File -> Print works, nor Ctrl + P, nor anything else...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is certainly an Adobe bug.
A long-running post up to 2018,
[Acrobat DC cannot print PDF files](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2088409)
on the Adobe forums, united many users suffering the same problem with
many suggested workarounds that worked for some but not for others:

1. Try to disable your anti-virus and if this works exclude the Adobe program folder
2. Printer name should be longer than 10 characters
3. In *Preferences > Security (Enhanced)*, disable *Enhanced Security* and OK
4. Try running Reader as admin
5. Check in Task Manager if another Reader task is executing and terminate it
6. Using `regedit`, delete all `Adobe` entries under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Adobe`
   and restart the Reader
7. Using `regedit`, create under
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Adobe\Adobe Acrobat\DC`
   a sub-key named `FeatureState` and create a new *DWORD (32-bit)* value
   named `4211929` and set it to `1`.
8. Do not print files from network shares requiring UNC paths
9. Save the file to the local desktop and print from there
10. If all fails, use another product for printing.

Comment: I only tried step 4 once, and after that even in simple launch, it started showing the Print Dialog and I'm able to print. Very much thank you... Will award bounty in few days.